# Assign Ajax Callback function value to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a function called getData which makes an ajax request. I want to use this ajax request result on my form submission for validation along with other validation.
Since ajax is asynchronous i am calling a callback function inside my success function.

Now i want to assign the callback function value to a javascript variable for my form validation.
I have tried using jquery validation submit handler method but that doesnt work either.
My callback function is returning the desired output, but when i try to console.log the variable i have assigned it too, it returns undefined

Here is my code

```
function getData(cb){
    $.ajax({
             url:'/stops/reason_valid',
              method: 'get',
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(data)    {
               if(data.reason == '6'){
                   if(($('.search_of_item1').is(':checked')) || ($('.search_of_item2').is(':checked'))){
                      $(".searchValidError").hide();
                      cb(false);
                    }
                    else{
                         $(".searchValidError").show();
                         cb(true);
                    }
               }
            }
          })
  }

  $(".actionstaken_submit").click(function(e){

    var validationFailed = false;
    var searchValidation = getData(function(cb){
          alert(cb);
          return cb;
          });
    console.log(searchValidation);

    if($('.no_validation').is(":checked")){
      if($('.action_validation:checked').length > 1){
        $('.noneError').show();
        validationFailed = true;
      }
      else{
        $('.noneError').hide();
        validationFailed =  validationFailed || false;
      }
    }

    if (validationFailed || searchValidation) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
  });
```

Note: if i do `alert(cb)` display's the appropriate value but `console.log(searchValidation)` returns undefined

Comment: `getData()` doesn't return anything

Comment: you forgot to close the apostrophe in:
        url:'/stops/reason_valid,

Comment: I updated my question, the thing is my ajax works properly fine as in my alert i get the cb value as true or false based on the condition, i am just able to assign cb value to the `searchvalidation` variable, any idea of how can i do that? @Anatsu

Comment: I tried returning cb from my getdata function but that doesnt help either @Taplar

Comment: `getData()` invokes an ajax method.  You are trying to treat asynchronous logic like synchronous logic.  It's not going to work with returns

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ....Since ajax is asynchronous i am calling a callback function inside my success function.

Right. But there is an issue. You continue to fail when you write:

```
var searchValidation = getData(function(cb){
      alert(cb);
      return cb;
});
console.log(searchValidation);
```

This is like you are doing the same error: the function is asynchronous as the call. There is more than one approach to solve your issue.
I suggest you to consider the jQuery event property **isTrigger**. When you rise an event with [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event object contains such a property.

Hence, you can change your code to:

```
$(".actionstaken_submit").click(function (e) {
            if (e.isTrigger !== undefined) { // <-- is event risen from .trigger() ?
                return;
            }
            e.preventDefault();

            var validationFailed = false;

            if ($('.no_validation').is(":checked")) {
                if ($('.action_validation:checked').length > 1) {
                    $('.noneError').show();
                    validationFailed = true;
                }
                else {
                    $('.noneError').hide();
                    validationFailed = validationFailed || false;
                }
            }

            getData(function (searchValidation) {
                console.log(searchValidation);
                if (!(validationFailed || searchValidation)) {
                    $(".actionstaken_submit").trigger('click'); // <-- raise the event
        }
    });
});
```

Another solution can be based on triggering the submit event:

```
$(".actionstaken_submit").closest('form').trigger('submit');
```

```js
function getData(cb) {
    cb($(':checkbox').prop('checked'));
    return;
    // for debug purposes....
    $.ajax({
        url: '1.json',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.reason == '6') {
                if (($('.search_of_item1').is(':checked')) || ($('.search_of_item2').is(':checked'))) {
                    $(".searchValidError").hide();
                    cb(false);
                }
                else {
                    $(".searchValidError").show();
                    cb(true);
                }
            } else {
                cb(false); // <-------  added.....
            }
        }
    })
}
$(".actionstaken_submit").click(function (e) {
    if (e.isTrigger !== undefined) { // <-- is event risen from .trigger() ?
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();

    var validationFailed = false;

    if ($('.no_validation').is(":checked")) {
        if ($('.action_validation:checked').length > 1) {
            $('.noneError').show();
            validationFailed = true;
        }
        else {
            $('.noneError').hide();
            validationFailed = validationFailed || false;
        }
    }

    getData(function (searchValidation) {
        console.log(searchValidation);
        if (!(validationFailed || searchValidation)) {
            $(".actionstaken_submit").trigger('click'); // <-- raise the event
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form >
    <input type="checkbox"> searchValidation?<br/>
    <input type="submit" class="actionstaken_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I change the code on the fly but what you have to do is run the validations of your click event inside a callback, or a deferred method as done or then.

Example:

```
function getData(){
   return $.ajax({
             url:'/stops/reason_valid',
              method: 'get',
             dataType: "json"
          })
  }

      function validate_submit(e){

  var validationFailed = false;
        var searchValidation = false;
     getData(searchValidation,validationFailed)
     .done((data)=>{


         console.log(data);
        if(data.reason == '6'){
      if(($('.search_of_item1').is(':checked')) || ($('.search_of_item2').is(':checked'))){
        $(".searchValidError").hide();
      }
      else{
        $(".searchValidError").show();
       searchValidation = true;
      }
    }
     }).always(()=>{
         console.log(searchValidation);
         if($('.no_validation').is(":checked")){
      if($('.action_validation:checked').length > 1){
        $('.noneError').show();
        validationFailed = true;
      }
      else{
        $('.noneError').hide();
        validationFailed =  validationFailed || false;
      }
    }

    if (validationFailed || searchValidation) {
       e.preventDefault();
       alert('oh shit here we go again');
       return false;
    }
     })
return false;
}

  $(".actionstaken_submit").click(function(e){
       validate_submit(e);
  });
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: This works but for some reason even after entering this`if (validationFailed || searchValidation) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }` code it ends up submitting my form @stan Chacon

Comment: add return false outside of the ajax call thats the only way

Comment: Even the edited version always submitted the form @stan Chacon